# Hibernate validate the @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) field

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a POJO with one of the fields mapped using hibernate:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "status")
private UserStatus status;
```

The enum has only 2 possible values: Activated and Deactivated

In my Controller, I have this simple method for saving the entity in the db:

```
@PostMapping("/save")
private UserDto saveUser(@RequestBody User user){
    return userService.save(user);
}
```

If I try to save the user with an inexistent `UserStatus` I get the following error message:

```
"message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.example.demo.utils.UserStatus` from String \"Deactivated1\": value not one of declared Enum instance names: [Deactivated, Activated]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.example.demo.utils.UserStatus` from String \"Deactivated1\": value not one of declared Enum instance names: [Deactivated, Activated]\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 3, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.example.demo.entity.User[\"status\"])",
```

How can I handle the serialization of inexistent values? I want to throw a custom exception in this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may add an ExceptionHandler in your Controller like

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleException() {
   // create custom error response
}`
```

or if you want to handle this situation in general, for all controllers you can use a ControllerAdvice.

Comment: yeah but it is a serialization error and I would like to know other methods as well

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand what you're trying to achieve. But for instance to have more control about the serialization process, one can think of a custom _Jackson-Deserializer_ for your User-Pojo which takes special care of unwanted values for enums.